# In input type text why am i unable to add - using javascript after four letters are typed?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am just trying to create something like this -
in html i have a input type text and whenever the legth of the value of the input is 2 then javascript will add a hyphen after this like -
if the value id "sd" then javascript will make it "sd-",
its working on console but its not changing the value of the input visually (user cant see).

i want a solution that change the value of the input and i can see that a hyphen added in the input.

```js
let dateA = document.getElementById("dateOne");


dateA.onkeyup = function(){
    let dataAValue = this.value;
    let dataAValueLength = this.value.length;
   if(dataAValueLength == 2) {

   let valueReplaced = dataAValue.replace(`${dataAValue}`, `${dataAValue}-`) 
//    console.log(dataAValue);
   dataAValue = valueReplaced;
  
   }
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="dateOne">
```

Comment: There's no need to use `.replace()`, just write `valueReplaced = dataAValue + "-";`

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the variable .You need to modify the object `this`

You can clean up your code by just using `+` instead of `replace` and use ternary operator instead of `if-else`

```js
let dateA = document.getElementById("dateOne");
dateA.onkeyup = function(){
    this.value += this.value.length === 2 ? '-' : ''
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateOne">
```